# Problem with data frame transformation using dplyr package

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Problem**

Let's consider two data frames :

One containing only 1's and 0's and second one with data :

```
set.seed(20)
df<-data.frame(sample(0:1,5,T),sample(0:1,5,T),sample(0:1,5,T))

#zero_one data frame
  sample.0.1..5..T. sample.0.1..5..T..1 sample.0.1..5..T..2
1                 0                   1                   0
2                 1                   0                   0
3                 1                   1                   1
4                 0                   0                   0
5                 1                   0                   1
df1<-data.frame(append(rnorm(4),10),append(runif(4),-5),append(rexp(4),20))

#with data
  append.rnorm.4...10. append.runif.4....5. append.rexp.4...20.
1           0.08609139            0.2374272           0.3341095
2          -0.63778176            0.2297862           0.7537732
3           0.22642990            0.9447793           1.3011998
4          -0.05418293            0.8448115           1.2097271
5          10.00000000           -5.0000000          20.0000000
```

Now what I want to do is to change values in second data frame for which first data frame takes values 0 by mean calculated for values for which first data frame takes value one.

**Example**

In first column I want to replace `0.08609139` and `-0.05418293` (values for which first column in first data frame takes values 0) by `mean(-0.63778176, 0.22642990,10.00000000)` (values for which first column in first data frame takes values 1).

I want to do it using `mutate_all()` function from `dplyr` package.

**My work so far**

```
  df1<-df1 %>% mutate_all(
      function(x) ifelse(df[x]==0, mean(x[df==1],na.rm=T,x)))
```

I know that the condition df[x] is meaningless, but I have no idea what should i put there. Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: I currently don't have acces to R so can't run anything to test, but here's a suggestion: multiply df with df1, so that the append.rnorm values for cases where sample is 0 is also set to zero. Then calculate the mean per append.rnorm column and replace any zero's in df by these column means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow @deschen's suggestion and multiply the two data frames together.

Here is another approach to consider using `mapply`. For each column, identify the positions (indices) in `df` where value is zero.

Then, substitute the corresponding `df1` column of those positions with the mean of other values in the column. `y[-idx]` should be all values in the `df1` column that exclude those positions.

Note that my `set.seed` is different - when I used yours of 20 I got different values, and a column with all zeroes. Please let me know if you are able to reproduce.

```
set.seed(12)

df<-data.frame(sample(0:1,5,T),sample(0:1,5,T),sample(0:1,5,T))
df1<-data.frame(append(rnorm(4),10),append(runif(4),-5),append(rexp(4),20))

my_fun <- function(x, y) {
  idx <- which(x == 0)
  y[idx] <- mean(y[-idx])
  return(y)
}

mapply(my_fun, df, df1)
```